# Java: Messager vs runtime exception

Tags: java, runtimeexception, annotations-processing-messager

In annotation processing, I am looking for a general guide as to when to use [`Messager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Messager.html), with `Diagnostic.Kind.ERROR` and when to use runtime exception. I know that using `Messager` will raise an error in the environment.

Let's consider this example. I have an annotation that is put on top of interfaces. The job of its processor is to make sure that all the methods wherein have a unique identifier of a specific type. If the processor encounters a violation, should it use `Messager`, or should it throw a runtime exception?

One disadvantage of `Messager` is that if that violation causes other issues in the program and other processors, the error message gets lost in other error messages and pollutes the logging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this paragraph from the documentation of [Processor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/processing/Processor.html) is a good general guide.

> If a processor throws an uncaught exception, the tool may cease other
> active annotation processors. If a processor raises an error, the
> current round will run to completion and the subsequent round will
> indicate an error was raised. Since annotation processors are run in a
> cooperative environment, a processor should throw an uncaught
> exception only in situations where no error recovery or reporting is
> feasible.